# Binary .dat file Plotting Column Array values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have imported an array into my IPython notebook using the following method:

```
SDSS_local_AGN = np.fromfile('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/SDSS_local_AGN_Spectra.dat', dtype=float)
```

The array is of the form:

```
 SPECOBJID_1         RA          DEC           SUBCLASS ...
 299528159882143744  146.29988   -0.12001413   AGN      ...
 299532283050747904  146.32957   -0.30622363   AGN      ...
```

Essentially each column has a header, and I now need to plot certain values.

As an example, I want to plot RA against DEC...how would I go about doing this?

Perhaps:

```
axScatter.plot(SDSS_local_AGN[RA], SDSS_local_AGN[DEC])
```

Comment: `np.fromfile(file, dtype=float)` (using the default `sep=''`) reads a binary file of floating point values.  How can your array have "columns" containing integers (`SPECOBJID_1`) or strings (`SUBCLASS`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer is mistaken, see comments

If you want to access them via name, you should use pandas instead of numpy.  In numpy, you need to lookup by index:

```
plt.scatter(SDSS_local_AGN[1], SDSS_local_AGN[2])
```

But in pandas, it would be as simple as:

```
df = read_csv('myfile')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='RA', y='DEC')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#scatter-plot

`SDSS_local_AGN['RA']` is a valid operation in pandas, but not in `numpy`.

PS, since you are working in a Notebook, pandas DataFrames will nicely render as HTML tables, making them much more readable.

Comment: Correction: `SDSS_local_AGN['RA']` *is* valid in numpy, if `SDSS_local_AGN` is a structured array (see docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). If the file was a text file with the layout shown in the question, it could be read into a structured array with, for example, `SDSS_local_AGN = np.genfromtxt('filename.dat', names=True)`.  However, it is binary file, so neither `np.genfromtxt` nor `pandas.read_csv` will work.

Comment: I didn't realize this, sorry.

Comment: The question is confusing (to me, anyway).  I don't see how the binary data read with `np.fromfile(...)` can have the "columns" shown in the question.

Comment: I'm wondering if OP used "genfromtxt" and posted "fromfile" instead?